# Recursive list using os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to build a list of path names.  The code I have so far is :

```
os.chdir(inputDir)

if Resursive is False:
    filePathList = [os.path.join(inputDir, f) for f in os.listdir(inputDir) if f.endswith('.tif')]

if Resursive is True:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.tif'):
                filePathList = (os.path.join(root, file))
```

Obviously this causes a problem where in the `Recursive is True` case the `filePathList` gets overwritten each time.  In other languages I'd do something like `filePathList[i] = (os.path.join(root, file))` but using `walk` `file` and `files` aren't numbers that can be used as index values.

What's the best way to handle in the `Recursive is True` case?

Comment: Before loop declare a variable `filePathList  = []`, In the if condition at last line Try `filePathList.append(os.path.join(root, file))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
os.chdir(inputDir)

if Resursive is False:
    filePathList = [os.path.join(inputDir, f) for f in os.listdir(inputDir) if f.endswith('.tif')]

if Resursive is True:
    filePathList = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.tif'):
                filePathList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```